# (Python) Using numpy.genfromtxt for filling list with data (different datatypes)

Tags: python, list, numpy, types, genfromtxt

i have an data.txt like that

```
16.37.235.153|119.222.242.130|38673|161|17|62|4646|
16.37.235.153|119.222.242.112|56388|161|17|62|4646|
16.37.235.200|16.37.235.153|59009|514|17|143|21271|
```

I want to get a list with the form:

```
list=[['16.37.235.153','119.222.242.130',38673,161,17,62,4646]
      ['16.37.235.153','119.222.242.112',56388,161,17,62,4646]
      ['16.37.235.200','16.37.235.153',59009,514,17,143,21271]]
```

I tried to use numpy.genfromtxt with dtype=None, but then i get:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Reading unicode strings without specifying the encoding argument is deprecated. Set the encoding, use None for the system default.
  list = numpy.genfromtxt('results.rw', dtype=None, delimiter = '|')
```

And this as list:

```
[['8.254.200.14' 'False']
 ['8.254.200.14' 'False']
 ['8.254.200.46' 'False']
 ...
 ['217.243.224.144' 'False']
 ['217.243.224.144' 'False']
 ['217.243.224.144' 'False']]
```

Appreciate every help, thank you in advance.

Greetings :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [71]: txt = '''16.37.235.153|119.222.242.130|38673|161|17|62|4646|
    ...: 16.37.235.153|119.222.242.112|56388|161|17|62|4646|
    ...: 16.37.235.200|16.37.235.153|59009|514|17|143|21271|
    ...: '''
```

That `encoding` warning is a nuisance, but not significant.

With dtype=None, you should get a structured array, one `field` per column:

```
In [74]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), encoding=None, dtype=None,delimiter='|')
In [75]: data
Out[75]: 
array([('16.37.235.153', '119.222.242.130', 38673, 161, 17,  62,  4646, False),
       ('16.37.235.153', '119.222.242.112', 56388, 161, 17,  62,  4646, False),
       ('16.37.235.200', '16.37.235.153', 59009, 514, 17, 143, 21271, False)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U13'), ('f1', '<U15'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<i8'), ('f5', '<i8'), ('f6', '<i8'), ('f7', '?')])
```

This is 1d.

And as a list of lists (or tuples)

```
In [76]: data.tolist()
Out[76]: 
[('16.37.235.153', '119.222.242.130', 38673, 161, 17, 62, 4646, False),
 ('16.37.235.153', '119.222.242.112', 56388, 161, 17, 62, 4646, False),
 ('16.37.235.200', '16.37.235.153', 59009, 514, 17, 143, 21271, False)]
```

Looks like it's filling in a final field (after the last `|`) with a boolean `False`.  That can probably be changed with some `filling` parameter.

Or limit the usecols to omit it

```
In [77]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), encoding=None, dtype=None,delimiter='|',u
    ...: secols=range(7))
In [78]: data
Out[78]: 
array([('16.37.235.153', '119.222.242.130', 38673, 161, 17,  62,  4646),
       ('16.37.235.153', '119.222.242.112', 56388, 161, 17,  62,  4646),
       ('16.37.235.200', '16.37.235.153', 59009, 514, 17, 143, 21271)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U13'), ('f1', '<U15'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<i8'), ('f5', '<i8'), ('f6', '<i8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

you might get nearer using something like

```
a = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', dtype=['S16', 'S16', 'i8', 'i8', 'i8', 'i8','i8'], delimiter='|')
```

but you seem to be mixing strings and integers so maybe you should use two arrays

EDIT w.r.t. your further (unrelated question):

One way to get the frequency of an item in a numpy array is to sum a boolean array resulting from a where or equality test. i.e.

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 10, (20000000,2))
(a == 7).sum()
=> 4442874
(a[:,0] == 7).sum()
=> 2220661
(a[:,1] == 7).sum()
=> 2222213
etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys, i already fixed it. I used the wrong file in genfromtxt.. my file i used had only 1 column...

Other question: Can someone tell me how i can count the occurrence of a value in a numpy ndarray.

Comment: Hi, bit confusing to add additional question but I've added to my answer.